# Unit test request retry python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to retry a request a couple times if the endpoint times out before returning results. Here's the code:

```
def retry_request(self, params, max_retries=3):
    for i in xrange(max_retries):
        try:
            response = requests.get(params)
            break
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
            raise e
```

I'd like to unit test the retries to show the retry logic works. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

I usually prefer not to make actual calls out to the internet in my tests: the remote service could be down or you might need to run your tests offline. Most importantly you want to run your tests **FAST**, and the network call can slow them down significantly.

I also want to make sure that the retry logic makes the retries I expect, and that it can actually succeeds eventually.

I tried to write a test doing that myself, but I struggled. I asked The Internet, but could not find anything doing what I wanted. I've digged into the magic world of `urllib3` and finally got to the bottom of it, but it took me a while.

Since this post came up while searching, I'll leave my solution here for posterity, trying to save someone else the hours I've spent trying:

```py
import urllib3
from http.client import HTTPMessage
from unittest.mock import ANY, Mock, patch, call

import requests


def request_with_retry(*args, **kwargs):
    session = requests.Session()
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=urllib3.Retry(
        raise_on_status=False,
        total=kwargs.pop("max_retries", 3),
        status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],  # The HTTP response codes to retry on
        allowed_methods=["HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],  # The HTTP methods to retry on
    ))
    session.mount("https://", adapter)
    session.mount("http://", adapter)
    return session.request(*args, **kwargs)


@patch("urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool._get_conn")
def test_retry_request(getconn_mock):
    getconn_mock.return_value.getresponse.side_effect = [
        Mock(status=500, msg=HTTPMessage()),
        Mock(status=429, msg=HTTPMessage()),
        Mock(status=200, msg=HTTPMessage()),
    ]

    r = request_with_retry("GET", "http://any.url/testme", max_retries=2)
    r.raise_for_status()

    assert getconn_mock.return_value.request.mock_calls == [
        call("GET", "/testme", body=None, headers=ANY),
        call("GET", "/testme", body=None, headers=ANY),
        call("GET", "/testme", body=None, headers=ANY),
    ]
```

*(Note: if you are making several calls to this method, then you might want to initialize the session object only once, not every time you make a request!)*

Comment: This is really useful for unit tests. The tests in my case were full system tests - But in truth I'm missing unit tests from my suite so will use this pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The requests library has its own retry logic.

Try something like this:

```
from requests import Session, exceptions
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from unittest import TestCase
import logging


class TestRequests(TestCase):

    def test_retries(self):
        session = Session()
        retries = Retry(total=5,
                        backoff_factor=0.1,
                        status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504, 429],
                        method_whitelist=frozenset(['GET', 'POST']))

        session.mount(
            'https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries,
                                    pool_maxsize=30))

        try:
            result = session.get('https://httpbin.org/status/500',
                                 stream=True,
                                 timeout=2)
            print(result)
        except exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            logging.error('http', exc_info=e)
        except exceptions.RetryError as e:
            logging.error('retry', exc_info=e)
```

Comment: Edit: @Enrico M. below reminded me that I missed error 429 out of the list of status_forcelist above. This is important for APIs with usage limits.